# Does the Office 365 Discovery Service still work with new applications

Tags: office365api

We have been trying to use the O365 Discovery Service to find the endpoint for OneDrive For Business so that our application can store data on the cloud.

We authenticate with Azure successfully and receive the code back.

We redeem the code for an access token successfully.

When we use the access token to access the discovery service, we get "App blocked calling O365 Discovery Service".

This only seems to be an issue when we register new applications (for about a month) while existing applications still work.

Now the discovery service is being depreciated and will be discontinued at the end of next year but it should still work until then.

Does anyone know if Microsoft has done something to the discovery service to prevent newly registered apps from being able to access the discovery service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, discovery service are being deprecated beginning January 10, 2018, so the new registered app is not supported is normal behavior.

> The Office 365 discovery service and SDK for .NET **are being
>   deprecated beginning January 10, 2018**, and will be **fully
>   decommissioned on November 1**, 2019. Start using Microsoft Graph to
>   access Office 365 data in a single endpoint. For more details, see our
>   announcement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/discovery-service-rest-operations